# Finding an item in a list

Tags: python, list, parsing

So I'm trying to find an item in a list in python. Here is my function:

```
def operator(input):
    operatorlist = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'sin', 'cos']

    for i in operatorlist:
        if input is operatorlist[i]:
            return True
```

My code is breaking, and I can't figure out why... any ideas?

I changed my code from:

```
def operator(input):
    if input is '+' or input is '-' or input is '*' or input is '/' or input is '^' or input is 'sin' or input is 'cos':
    return True
```

Because I was told that is was, essentially, stylistically dumb to write it that way.

Comment: Why not use a set instead of a list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One line :

```
return input in operatorlist
```

No need to do conditions here, the in operator already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

- Function definition lines need to end with a colon.
- Indentation matters.
- You almost never want to use 'is'.
- You can check to see if an object is in a list without explicitly looping over it using the 'in' operator.
- You should probably return False if you don't find what you're looking for; mostly you'll get away with it, because a function returns None if you don't explicitly return, and None is not "truthy".

So try:

```
def operator(input):
    operatorlist = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'sin', 'cos']

    if input in operatorList:
        return True

    return False
```

or even more tersely:

```
def operator(input):
    operatorlist = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'sin', 'cos']
    return input in operatorList
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` operator:

```
return (input in operatorlist)
```

(The parentheses aren't necessary, I've included them to make it clearer.)

You might want to go through [a tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), or a [book](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/), to get started with Python.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `is` for comparison. The change you suggest doesn't address why the above user is seeing an error, which has to do with the way the variable `i` is used. It's assigned as an element from the list, but then treated like it should be an index.

Comment: @EMS: There is [plenty wrong](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/) with using `is` for comparing strings. Also, a `for` loop instead of an `in` is just adding complexity and overhead for no reason.

Comment: Only use `is` if you really mean to test for same object by identity vs. by value. Unfortunately, CPython interns short strings, so that `'s' is 's'` will often return True, and so many beginners form this bad habit of using `is` for comparing strings. They get sucked in because `'012345'[0] is '0'` evaluates True, then are surprised by bugs because `'012345'[0:3] is '012'` evaluates False. This is not guaranteed by the language spec, and Jython and PyPy don't behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

`for i in operatorlist` does not run over the indices of operatorlist but the actual elements. So `i` will be `'+'` in the first loop, `'-'` in the second and so on.

So this `if input is operatorlist[i]` should be something like `if input is i`.

Finally, actually this whole function can be replaced by the logical operation `input in operatorlist`. So you could do something like:

```
def operator(input):
    return input in ('+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'sin', 'cos')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def operator(x):
    return x in {'+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'sin', 'cos'}
```

You might want to avoid creating a new set for each function call though, in which case you can do...

```
def operator_check(*operators):
    operators = set(operators)
    def checker(x):
        return x in operators
    return checker

math_operator = operator_check('+', '/', '*', '^', '-')

if math_operator('+'):
    print "it's a math operator!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `for i in operatorlist` to `for i in range(len(operatorlist))`

When you just ask for `i in operatorlist`, then at each iteration `i` will actually be the element, and not the index, of that entry. Alternatively, you can reformat your loop's body to reflect that `i` is an actual string containing the operator in question, and not an index.

Comment: Or even better, change the loop to `for item in operatorlist`, and drop the indexing operation altogether.

Comment: My mistake.  But `i` is traditionally an index, so that sentence would be more clear if you used a more descriptive name, such as `item` or `operator`.

Comment: I agree, but was just sticking with the OP's notation. You make a good point.

Comment: Why not use enumerate instead?

Comment: Look, no one's disputing that there are other ways. I mention directly in my answer that `for i in operatorlist` means `i` is an element, and so re-writing the for-loop to handle this is a good solution. If you don't need the index at all, then `enumerate()` is a waste of time. I still don't see why these stylistic opinions would be grounds for downvoting a syntactically correct answer that is not out of the norm for Python syntax.

Comment: @EMS - there are accepted idioms in Python, and they are accepted for good reason. You can write Python using FORTRAN or C style idioms if you like, but your code will be bloated and slow. Iterating over a list by index when the real goal is to iterate over the list's items is wasteful and really, it is the mark of a beginner. `for item in sequence:` avoids computing the length of the sequence, and creating an extra range (an entire list of the list indexes if you are still using Python 2.x), and really is just less syntax to have to digest later.

Comment: In this particular case (teaching a beginner), it is extremely important to use pythonic idioms. You can break the rules if you know them and have a good reason, but neither is the case here. The rules exist to make everyone's code look similar (there should only one way to do it). Following them makes *all code that follows them* more readable and, ultimately, maintainable. Maybe not in scientific circles, but be prepared for people yelling at you for breaking them without good reason. The yellers are defending the ecosystem, making it easier for *them* to take over someone else's code.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote, but to be quite honest these opinions are better suited for a blog post.  To the substance: as @Petr points out, maintainability is a core reason for a consistent style throughout a language.  If your boss wants everything written to look like C++, then that works for your company because people at your company expect everything to look like C++.  However, in 90%+ of real-world situations, Python should be written to look like Python, not like C++, because that's how the next person to modify it will expect it to look.

Comment: @EMS If you want to use style suited for scientific computing in your answer, then answer questions about scientific computing.  You wouldn't answer a Java question with Python code, so why answer a general-purpose Python question with a style of Python that's used in scientific computing but not elsewhere?