# Python - Find input answer in a list, answer is one of the list element

Tags: python, list

Let say I ask the user whether to start the quiz and there a possibilities of answer like yes, yeah, and yea.

I want to put the possible answer in a list and make python runs through every single of the element in the list and check if they are equal.

```
if answer.lower() == 'yeah yes yep yea'.split(): 
    .... blocks of code ....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding an item in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150011/finding-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` operator:

```
if answer.lower() in 'yeah yes yep yea'.split():
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> 'YeAH'.lower() in 'yeah yes yep yea'.split()
True
>>> 'Yee'.lower() in 'yeah yes yep yea'.split()
False
```

It's better to define the list/tuple first instead if creating a list each time(In case you're doing this is a loop):

```
>>> lis = 'yeah yes yep yea'.split()
>>> 'yes' in lis
True
```

---

[In Python3.2+ it is recommended to use `set` literals](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations):

> Python’s peephole optimizer now recognizes patterns such `x in {1, 2,
>   3}` as being a test for membership in a set of constants. The optimizer
>   recasts the set as a `frozenset` and stores the pre-built constant.

Now that the speed penalty is gone, it is practical to start writing membership tests using set-notation. This style is both semantically clear and operationally fast:

```
if answer.lower() in {'yeah', 'yes', 'yep', 'yea'}:
    #pass
```

Comment: I thought it will be faster to use the split() method.

Comment: @user2945752 If you're doing this multiple times then it's better to just split once and assign it to a variable.

Comment: so creating it first will make it runs faster? What about tuple, since it is read only I think it is quicker

Comment: @user2945752 For 4 items the speed is not going to matter much. My point is if you're checking this condition multiple times(for loop, or while loop) then it's better to create the `list, tuple`(or set literal in py3.2+), just once, instead of splitting the string again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a string then splitting why don't you use a list of your possible answers?

```
if answer.lower() in ['yes', 'yeah', 'Yeah', 'yep', 'yea']: # you can add more options to the list
    # code
```